# uninitialized constant User::follow Extracted source (around line #28):

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-6

i have an error in my user.rb model (around line #28):

```
27def following?(user) 
28 following.include?(user)
29end
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?
Showing C:/instagramm/instagram-clone/app/views/accounts/profile.html.erb where line #11 raised:
my profile.html.erb :

```
<% if @users.image.present %>
<%= image_tag @users.image %>
<% end %>


<strong><h1><%= @users.full_name %></h1></strong>

<% if user_signed_in? && @user == current_user %>

      <%= link_to"Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path(@user) %>
    <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
        <%= link_to"Unfollow", follows_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :delete %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to"Follow", follows_path(user_id: @user.id) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>


<div> <%= @users.posts.count %> Posts </div>




<p><%= @users.full_name %></p>
<p><%= @users.description %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'User Website', @users.website if @users.website.present? %></p>



<%= @posts.each do |post|%>
<%= image_tag post.image %>
<% end %>
```

my model : follow.rb

```
class Follow < ApplicationRecord
    
    

    belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'user'
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: 'user'

    validates :follower_id, presence: true
    validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

and this is my user.rb model : the error is around(#line28) in def following?(user)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :posts 
  validates :username, presence: true 
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

has_one_attached :image

has_many :active_follows, class_name: "follow", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy 

has_many :passive_follows, class_name: "follow", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy

has_many :following, through: :active_follows, source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_follows, source: :follower

def follow(user)
  active_follows.create(followed_id: user.id)
end

def unfollow(user)
  active_follows.find_by(followed_id: user.id).destroy 
end

def following?(user)
following.include?(user)
end 

def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end



end
```

Comment: Try `User::Follow` if you're manually referencing it, or add the whole error you're getting and all the files involved in the problem (look at the backtrace).

Comment: Nothing in your code makes any mention of `follow` (all lower-case). You mention `followed`, `following`, `follower`, `follower_id` and `Follow`, but not `follow`. Can you please just check really carefully that the information in your post is 100% correct?

Comment: yes the information is 100% correct :) , i don't understand what can i do exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails assumes that association points to a class with matching name, so in this case your `following` association will search for `Following` class.

Obviously it is not what you need here - having a quick guess by the code structure that you expect `following` to return a collection of Users, so you need to tell that to your association:

```
has_many :following, through: :active_follows, source: :followed, class_name: 'User'
```

It is also important to use correct class names given to `class_name` option. It has to match the name of the ActiveRecord class exactly, so it must be `"Follow"` not `"follow"` and, similarly, `"User"` not `"user"`

Comment: i have change this line but it still the same error, i don't understand the problem exactly

Comment: @FazaaMajdeddine Is it exactly the same or is slightly different? :) Try in the console if you can do `User.new.active_follows` as well.

Comment: yes the same , and thank you very much bro :)

Comment: User.new.active_follows
   (3.4ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
NameError (uninitialized constant User::follow)
        from (irb):1

Comment: Yup, as expected. class_name option must match ruby class name exactly, so it is `Follow`, not `follow (capital F)`. Fix in all the other places as well.

Comment: Follow instead of any follow ?

Comment: @FazaaMajdeddine Generally speaking - all class_name option should be a camel-case string. You have same mistake in the `Follow` class.

Answer (score 0):

You already got response from @BroiStase you are using incorrect name of classes in your code. Please change your Follow.rb

```
class Follow < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: 'User'
    validates :follower_id, presence: true
    validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

In your `User.rb` following you have to do following changes.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts 
  validates :username, presence: true 
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_one_attached :image
  has_many :active_follows, class_name: "Follow", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :passive_follows, class_name: "Follow", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_follows, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_follows, source: :follower

  def follow(user)
    active_follows.create(followed_id: user.id)
  end

  def unfollow(user)
    active_follows.find_by(followed_id: user.id).destroy 
  end

  def following?(user)
    following.include?(user)
  end 

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Please when you code avoid any extra spaces, line breaks and give proper 2 space indentions it will help you to understand code better. If still error please share error message also.